# bullets are not displaying with <ul>

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Bullets are not displaying. When i tried the same through jsFiddle, it works. What might be the reason?

```
         <div id="mainInfo" style="display: none;" title="Customer Information">
            <div id="greenCheck" style="display: none;">
                <img src= "IMAGE_SOURCE">
            </div>
            <div id="subInfo" style="display: none;">
            </div> 
         </div>
         <div>
            //button definition onclick="show()"![enter image description here][1]
         </div>

//javascript
function show() 
{
    var htmlstr = "<p><b>The customer provided the following:</b></p><br/><ul>";
    if(true)//some condition which i made true for testing
        {
             htmlstr = htmlstr + "<li>Date of Birth</li>";
             htmlstr = htmlstr + "<li>Social Security Number</li>";
        }
        htmlstr = htmlstr + "</ul>";
        document.getElementById('mainInfo').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('greenCheck').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('subInfo').style.display = 'block';
        jQuery("#subInfo").html(htmlstr);
        jQuery("#mainInfo").dialog({
              //dialog code
        }
}
```

list-style-type:none is applied through a css file. I modified at local file and it worked :)

Comment: No image.. I think you forgot to attach image. And Is there any css file that you are adding to your document? Show us your css code.

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R3LXG/1/

Comment: check using jquery link

Comment: @Unknown.. attached image.. it is taking default jquery ui css only.. plz check now

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool.. can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: Could you add a link instead of an image so we may examine all your CSS? Alternatively, use Chrome, right click on any list element and select "Inspect Element"

Comment: it looks like some css rule is setting `list-style-type: none;`

Comment: using browser developer tools inspect the style attributes of the `li` elements in the dialog

Comment: @ArunPJohny you are right..<ul> and <li> are declared with 'list-style-type: none;'.. instead of changing at css level.. is there any alternate way to disable 'list-style-type: none;' for this element only

Comment: see @JasonSperske answer below

Comment: @ArunPJohny.. edited question.. please check.. how to align bullets?

Answer (score 5):

You could add this CSS to make sure you get bullet point only in the list that you are dynamically adding:

```
#subInfo ul li {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Here are your options:

> Formal syntax: disc | circle | square | decimal | decimal-leading-zero
>   | lower-roman | upper-roman | lower-greek | lower-latin | upper-latin
>   | armenian | georgian | lower-alpha | upper-alpha | none

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

As for your updated question there are a lot of different approaches that would work, from putting the image and the bullet list in a table (what I tend to think is a bad idea), to using containing `DIV`s.  However if you didn't want to change the HTML (and the JavaScript) then perhaps adding a `padding-left` to the `li` in the CSS to push the list items to appear to line up with the text.  It's kind of a hack but it would be easy to reason about and require no change to the HTML.

Comment: your solution is working.. question is updated now.. can you please check

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely some CSS overriding the default behavior of list items. Try opening the web page in Google Chrome (or IE 8+) and pressing F12 to access the web developer tools.  You can then select a list item and view all of the styles that have been assigned to it.  I've tried your code on my machine without any CSS and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The elements are just flowing normally into position... Change some CSS and they will fall into place.

1. Get rid of that line break (`<br/>`), it just messes everything up!
2. Use `padding` on the `div` that contains the header (in this case the `p`) and the `ul` element to place everything exactly where you want.
3. Set the green "checked" icon as a background to that container `div`.
4. Give the `li` elements a style of your choice (bullet, circle, etc).